# Set up CORS in ASP.NET Core to allow wildcard origin without auth AND whitelisted domains with auth

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I have an API that serves a list of documents that are mostly publicly available. They are surfaced through a 1st party SPA, and they are also embeddable in other websites. Therefore, I need to allow all origins in CORS.

However, some of the documents are restricted, and requires authentication (for which I use a bearer token in the `Authorization` header). Therefore, I also have to allow credentials in CORS. (Note that only public documents are embeddable, so no auth is needed when embedding.)

Is it possible to configure this in ASP.NET Core?

- If I allow credentials, I can't allow wildcard domains.
- If I disallow credentials, then AFAIK the 1st party SPA won't send the necessary authorization for signed-in users.
- If I dynamically allow any domain (using `SetIsOriginAllowed` and always returning `true`), then AFAIK I open up for vulnerabilities if the 3rd party websites that embed data from the API are vulnerable to XSS.

It seems to me that what I need is to allow wildcard origins without authentication, AND allow specific (1st party) origins with authentication.

If there are no proper solutions but there are good workarounds, please let me know.

Possible workarounds I can think of:

- Deploy the API twice with different base URLs and CORS config (more complex devops)
- Dynamically allow any origin with credentials (security issue, see note earlier)
- Dynamically allow any origin with credentials, but manually block authenticated requests from non-whitelisted origins (non-standard, hacky)
- Disallow credentials in CORS and use a non-standard auth header for the bearer token (from the SPA). Would this cause security issues?

In case it's relevant, I'm using F# and Giraffe.

Comment: Are different CORS policies for different action methods a possible solution? You'd serve the public documetns over one endpoint and the secured ones over a different endpoint using a different policy.

Comment: I'm using [Giraffe](https://github.com/giraffe-fsharp/Giraffe) for routing. Not sure it's possible.

Comment: So you're using ... F#? Might be a good idea to add this to the tags. Seems to me as some worthwile information. Although Giraffe itself is just middleware to the asp.net core pipeline, I have no idea, how you'd use existing functionality in that framework or language.

Comment: Added a sentence at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is possible to implement this using `ICorsPolicyProvider`.

```ml
type CorsPolicyProvider(config: IConfiguration) =
  let origins = config.GetSection("CORS:Origins").Get<string []>()

  let configureCommonAndBuild (builder: CorsPolicyBuilder) =
    builder
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader()
      .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromMinutes 60.)
      .WithExposedHeaders((*...*))
      .Build()

  let allowCredentialsPolicy =
    CorsPolicyBuilder().WithOrigins(origins).AllowCredentials()
    |> configureCommonAndBuild

  let publicPolicy =
    CorsPolicyBuilder().AllowAnyOrigin()
    |> configureCommonAndBuild

  interface ICorsPolicyProvider with
    member _.GetPolicyAsync(ctx: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext, _policyName: string) =
      let policy =
        match ctx.TryGetRequestHeader "Origin" with
        | Some origin when origins |> Array.contains (origin.ToLowerInvariant()) -> allowCredentialsPolicy
        | _ -> publicPolicy
      Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult policy


type Startup(config: IConfiguration) =

  member _.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) : unit =
    services
      // ...
      .AddCors()
      .AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyProvider>(CorsPolicyProvider(config))
      // ...

  member _.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder) : unit =
    app
      // ...
      .UseCors()
      // ...
```